# messed up with mount and naming a partition - delete a folder in file system

Tags: partitioning, mount, automount

I have a partition /dev/sda8 which I want to name it "Documents" and automount.
Because I have a long time to use these commands ,I messed up a little (not that I am familiar).

I used gparted and gave a label "Documents" for the partition.
Then , I don't remember exact the order of the commands I used ,but sth like:

```
sudo mount -L Documents /dev/sda8
sudo mkdir /dev/sda8
sudo mkdir -p /dev/sda8
sudo mount /dev/sda8 /Documents
```

I added to fstab

> UUID=16b7ad55-aea9-49ed-8be9-0bbf1cb23c2e
>   /Documents    ext4    #defaults   02

The result now  is  that

1. I don't have a device named 'Documents'
2. I have a folder named 'Documents' in my file system (where /etc , /bin...etc lies)

How can I correct these?

-----------UPDATE--------------------------------------------------
I tried to umount (from the above commands) and now I have the device "Documents" but I still have a folder 'Documents' in file system which is empty and is 10GB!  How to delete that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did :

```
sudo umount /dev/sda8/ /Documents 
sudo umount Documents /dev/sda8/
sudo umount -L Documents /dev/sda8/
```

and suddenly the device "Documents" appeared!

As for the 'Documents' folder inside my file system that was my mistake.
I chekced the properites and it showed the space of the entire file system.My mistake.

Also, for details you can check [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8019/discussion-between-eliah-kagan-and-george).

I want to thank Eliah Kagan  for his help.