# How to retrive data on a internal harddisk that is partially broken

Tags: boot, hard-drive, data-recovery, error-handling

I recently experienced problems with my ubuntu 18.04 and no one couldn't actually help me out there

[The Root filesystem on dev/sda1 requires a manual fsck[This one needs a different approach,others are not working]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113705/the-root-filesystem-on-dev-sda1-requires-a-manual-fsckthis-one-needs--differen?noredirect=1#comment1838693_1113705)

So I want to reinstall it but I want to copy my data on the hard disk to some other drive. The problem is that after successful login, I can only work on the system for almost 1 minute before which it will end up in a black screen full of errors  https://drive.google.com/open?id=11r3gaAlU9Xlcjd10ir0Z_7n9cFq2dY1f

Please help me out in this

Comment: Have you checked the health of your disk?  (ie. SMART data which is from the electronics of the drive, and not disk itself).  Your photo reminds me of what you see with a failing disk (which is one reason a RW media can become RO).  I'd also use a 'live' system (eg. install media) to get your data off; if a 'live' system is validated & has problems, I'd do a 'cap-check' (ie. look for swollen capacitors) - ie. I'm suspicious of your hardware, and would ensure it's good before worrying about software-on-it.

Comment: @guivercI did run the tests and I got it was ok https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lHMSa5VH8YMy7O4IpOmAyLT-Zqsdm411   I do suspect the hard disk, I have plans to return it to the seller since it was bought just 5 months ago. Can you pls explain how to get the files by  using the live disk

Comment: @Xen2050 that one you mentioned, is about an external hard drive, mines is an internal one and there are no weird sounds coming from it

Comment: Based on your black screen full of errors, It looks like it's getting re-mounted read-only due to errors (causing further errors) [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/158970/225694) in the called duplicate is what you need.

Comment: There's no effective difference between data recovery of an external or internal drive, in fact an internal is probably easier with no extra interface to worry about. And sounds or quiet, something definitely appears wrong with your drive, some fail loudly & some just quit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a usb stick run a live os off it, transfer files, and make sure if ur gonna chekdisk it’s not an integrity checking read write heavy sort of check disk use something delicate to literally prod at the blocks of data

Comment: Dear @Curiouskangaroo I am sorry but I really didn't understand this line------ make sure if ur gonna chekdisk it’s not an integrity checking read write heavy sort of check disk use something delicate to literally prod at the blocks of data----I am a beginner and I am confused

Comment: To put it simple there are programs what have been made to check your hdd for damage some off these programs can be really heavy handed at checking the disk by writing and re-wrighting  and deleting writing again and again the software will just write and read as much as it can and if your hdd hard disk drive is nearly dead anyway and you wanna pull data off it before it folds giving it a hard durability test will be to intense for it and it will just pack up, do you have 2 usb sticks il help you now get what you want off your drive.

Comment: Do u have any other form of access to a Linux website to download an iso image and make a bootable live usb stick, soon as u get a usb or 2 or 1 usb stick and an external hdd you can do it easy literally no more then 5 steps and you’ve got your data off your drive

Comment: I tried using the live disk to get data out, but I am not able to retrieve half of the data, It seems like half of the files don't even have permission to be viewed, It cant be copied, it ends up in error

Comment: Thank u @Curiouskangaroo, I got all the data out, Do u have any specific test I should be running other than the disks SMART test?

Answer (score 0):

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

To retrieve any data you'll need:

- Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- some external destination to store your data

Then...

- boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `Files` window
- open a second new `Files` window showing your external storage
- single-click on your hard disk in the left window pane to mount it
- find your `Home` folder in the right window pane
- drag any important files from your `Home` folder to the second `Files` window

Comment: Dear @heynnema , i am not getting advanced options or root access option in the grub menu. Would you please also look into this  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113705/the-root-filesystem-on-dev-sda1-requires-a-manual-fsckthis-one-needs-a-differen?noredirect=1# because you did solve a similar one before, please...

Comment: @JoseBen then use the second method that I outlined for you. Use a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB... **not** a systemrescue DVD.

Comment: yeah, I did it now and got errors first then on the second attempt I believe there were no errors   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eM6GJ5ySgqN6lvneJywg8S7TZTRYu-8n       https://drive.google.com/open?id=1k9AECu9T9LYK2zxBW8uq3UPhChdalkJx I will  be rebooting it in a minute @heynnema

Comment: but what should I do after the reboot??? What if it's still back to where it was ?? Is there anything specific I should do @heynnema ?

Comment: @JoseBen  Do three things. Use the `Disks` app to monitor the `SMART Data & Tests`, and in `terminal`, keep a window visable with the command `tail -f /var/log/syslog` and watch for disk errors. Control-c to quit. Install `smartmontools`  if you don't already have it installed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88995/discussion-between-jose-ben-and-heynnema).

Comment: @JoseBen  Are you able to remove the disk and temporarily install it into another computer, or external case? That would eliminate a bad controller on your motherobard, or a bad cable. What brand of drive do you have? Does syslog show any disk errors?

Comment: @JoseBen see Update #1 in my answer.

Comment: @JoseBen `fsck` couldn't even complete without input/output errors, looks like it's not going to be permanently fixed anytime soon - if you wanted to retrieve data from the drive, your chances of doing so successfully could be decreasing with every new error.

Comment: I used the live disk to get data out but I am not able to retrieve  half of the data, It seems like half of the files don't even have permission to be viewed

Comment: @heynnema, I don't have another system lying around but had another older drive that I used for windows, I tried installing Ubuntu in it and its working fine, so the motherboard could be excluded I believe

Comment: @JoseBen you never told me what brand of HDD you have, or what errors were reported in syslog. Please remember to vote or accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @heynnema MInes is  Seagate 1tb hard disk, I have left photos of the errors on the main question, pls check

Comment: @JoseBen those errors aren't from syslog, are they. Anyway, it looks like your Seagate is toast. I left instructions for trying to get any data off of it.

Comment: Thanks to @Curiouskangaroo I got the data out, I ran the tests on the hard disk, came out okay, so I tried reinstalling ubuntu in it and it has been working fine for over 3 hours now. I don't think the hard disk is to blame