# fsck from util-linux 2.37.2

Tags: boot, fsck

My computer hung up so I forced it to turn off. When it restarted, I had this error message:

```
The root filesystem on /dev/sda2 requires a manual fsck.
```

So then I typed in `fsck -f /dev/sda1`

Then I got a message:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
(initramfs)
```

I typed in "help" and got a long list of commands.

I have no idea what to do that this point. Please pretend I am your grandmother as I do not understand the Ubuntu jargon.

Comment: *The root filesystem on **/dev/sda2** requires a manual fsck. So then I typed in fsck -f **/dev/sda1**.* What were you expecting exactly?

Comment: It could be a storage device faliure. You need to boot from an Ubuntu USB and try that command.

Comment: You need to type `fsck /dev/sda2` if that's the file system that needs it

Comment: My grandmother is a very sharp person, and has a lot of technical experience. I think you might want help that's a bit below her level.

Comment: Thanks all. @Nmath - your suggestion was great. Computer back up and running. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrive data on a internal harddisk that is partially broken](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113796/how-to-retrive-data-on-a-internal-harddisk-that-is-partially-broken)