# External drive with one bad sector

Tags: hard-drive, external-hdd

After one day with my External drive which stopped working, today, without doing anything, it's working again and I'm very glad.

But, when I checked the Disk I saw this

[image]

On assessment it says: Disk is OK, one bad sector

It's that something bad? How can I fix this?

Comment: -- Depends on the sector ;-) -- Keep an eye on this. IF it is problematic you will see those bad sectors increase rapidly the next few months.

Answer (score 4):

One bad sector is not a problem at all. Keep an eye on it, so check regularly.
When it starts increasing dramatically in a short time the disk may fail soon.
The system marks bad sectors as unusable - fixing bad sectors is impossible.
However you can continue to using your disk at the current status of health.

Answer (score 4):

A single bad sector **may** be entirely harmless and the drive **may** happily run with it for years.

**But** especially if you had experienced an issue with that drive it can also be a first sign of a dying drive. As it is an external drive you presumably use for backups I would not take this lightly. You need to find out about the cause of this warning.

Please do run a thorough self test on that drive to read out its SMART data. They will give you valuable additional information. Here's how:

- [How to run a checkdisk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59064/how-to-run-a-checkdisk)
- [How can I check the health of my hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38566/how-can-i-check-the-health-of-my-hard-drive)

Things to be worried about are:

- too many reallocated sectors indicate that the drive's firmware will no longer be able to reallocate and hide bad sectors to a reserved area of that drive.
- growing numbers of bad sectors over time indicate that your drive has an issue and **it will fail** in the near future.

From what we can see there are not too many data on that drive. So it may be fairly new. You may be eligible for a warranty replacement but you will have to  ask the vendor.

Comment: @Lurrdock Ouch - that indeed may be more serious than I thought. An [answer to this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/81621/external-hard-drive-failing-is-backup-recovery-possible) gives some suggestions. First of all I'd **check cables** (replace with another one). Unfortunately for a 5 TB drive `ddrescue` to recover data may not be a good option. In any case if you get your drive mounted you should backup your files (but there is quite a risk that the drive will ultimately fail by just using it).... Good luck!